# Using NSLevelIndicators with NSSliders Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, continuous, nsslider, nslevelindicator

I'm learning Objective-c and made a little practice app to take input from an NSSlider and set the level to it. However, I would like to know if there is any way to make the level indicator update with the dragging of the slider. Currently, it only updates when I let go of the slider. I saw a couple of references to a setContinuous method, but it didn't seem to do anything. If that method is completely unrelated, please constrain your laughter. Also, it would be awesome if you could add code snippets to show me where to put the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-setContinuous:` should do the trick, if you're sending it to the right object. Or, if you've set up your interface in a .xib file, check the 'continuous' box (I don't remember the actual label) for the slider.